# Sort <li> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have a language select which is a simple `<ul>` with `<li>`s and `<a>`s inside.

Every `<li>` has a class - `lang-inactive` or `lang-active`. It depends on what language the user is using right now.

The `<li>`s with `.lang-inactive` are hidden by default. When you `.hover()` the `ul` the other options are showed.

[image: Hovered - all languages]
[image: Not hovered - current language]

Here is a simple example.

But as you can see the first `<li>` is French, and when I'm using `English` and I hover the language bar the French appears over the english.

Is there a way I can sort the `<li>` depending on whether they are `lang-active` or `lang-inactive`. The inactive ones should appear below the active one.

My current code is:

```
var ul = $('#languages-iv');
    ul.css('position', 'absolute');
    ul.css('top', 5);
    li = ul.children('li');

    li.detach().sort(function(a,b) {
       //how do I sort
    });

    ul.append(li);
$("#languages-iv").hover(function(){
    $('.lang-inactive').slideToggle();
}, function() {
    $('.lang-inactive').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: There certainly is. What have you attempted, OP?

Comment: I'm confused.  Make a jsfiddle for us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This executed on page-load (or whenever your language selector gets created) should push the active language up to first child.

```
$('.lang-active').prependTo('#languages-iv');
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gqfPV/

Answer (score 2):

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="lang-active">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
    </ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul li').live('click',function(){
            $('li a').removeClass('lang-active');
            var elem = $(this);
            $(this).remove();
            $('ul').prepend(elem);
            $(this).children('a').addClass('lang-active');
        });
    });
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your sort:

```
var listItems = myList.children('li').get();
listItems.sort(function(a,b){
  return $(a).hasClass('lang-inactive') ? -1 : $(b).hasClass('lang-inactive') ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: bad console copy. got me :)